# ¿Como puedo cambiar un Spinner de acuerdo a otro Spinner?

Tags: android, eclipse

Tengo la siguiente interfaz, al momento de seleccionar una marca se deben poner los modelos de esa marca, pero no se como hacer que cambien los items de los modelos de acuerdo a la marca seleccionada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Para ello el **spinner** trae consigo un método que estará escuchando cada vez que sucede un cambio: **setOnItemSelectedListener**. Es muy fácil de usar y entender.

Te adjunto el ejemplo que generé para tu pregunta.

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

               //Sirve para obtener el valor del spinner 
                String marca = spinner.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); 

                if(marca.equals("Volkswagen")){
                    array2 = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lista2); 
                    spinner2.setAdapter(array2);

                }   else if(/*La otra marca*/){
                     //Cargar otra lista de modelos de la marca seleccionada
                }                 
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

El **onItemSelected** escuchará que marca se seleccionó y procederá a mostrar los resultados en otro spinner. Eso sería todo.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha funcionado muy bien, otra pregunta sabes si puedo agregarle el mismo Array a 2 Spinners?

Comment: Si, si se puede. En cualquier caso varios Spinner pueden tener una misma lista.